# Error: Invalid resource directory name for splash

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I have a Nuxt JS / Cordova 8.0.0 project with a few plugins. I'm trying to add custom splash screens to the project, and have added them inside of `res/screen/android/`

Every time I try to compile the project, I get the following error when building for Android:

`Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project-beacon/cordova/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi-portrait: Error: Invalid resource directory name`

This is really frustrating.

I have my `config.xml` file setup as follows:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <icon density="ldpi" height="36" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" width="36" />
    <icon density="mdpi" height="48" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" width="48" />
    <icon density="hdpi" height="72" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" width="72" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" height="96" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" width="96" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <splash src="res/splash/android/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <custom-config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    </custom-config-file>
</platform>
```

Originally, I had a load of splash screens, but due to the error, I've removed them to see if it would fix it. I have tried changing the file names and everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `<platform name="android">`

Also you have `<splash src="res/splash/android/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />` which has no density, remove it.

Comment: The double `platform` is a mistake in Stackoverflow when created, this does not exist in the actual config file, so this isn't the reason. In addition, the `universal` splash was the original one prior to adding the new set, and this originally worked, so keeping it here shouldn't break it as the error isn't referencing this path.